# Authorizing access to Google Cloud Functions with ID token from Identity Platform

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, authorization

**Intro**
So I have read official docs [Authenticating for invocation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) which is about helping developer testing and I got that working, but this approach requires a SA and a generated token. It seems the docs mix up "authentication" (proving identity) and "authorization" (giving access) which is not making it easier to get the whole picture.

I want to authorize Google Cloud Function with the user's ID token generated from Identity Platform. The official Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) says:
"When a user or device signs in using Firebase Authentication, Firebase creates a corresponding ID token that uniquely identifies them and grants them access to several resources, such as Realtime Database and Cloud Storage. You can re-use that ID token to authenticate the Realtime Database REST API and make requests on behalf of that user."

**My setup**
I got the following artifacts to test function authorization with user:

- A local React app with npm 'firebase' and a login form calling firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword.
  firebase is initialized with config fields apiKey and authDomain.
- An Express API deployed to Cloud Functions with default permissions, but I've provided the cloudbuild file with --allow-unauthenticated as an attempt to only focus on authorization.
- A local Postman request setup calling the Express API with authorization type=Bearer Token and token set to the ID token received in the React app's onAuthStateChanged from user.getIdToken()

The Postman request responds with 401 Unauthorized. Notice it says **Unauthorized**, not 403 Forbidden.

**Research**
When reading up on the topic, I came across the following approaches to solve my problem:

1. Fetch the user id from the token and push it to a custom backend service which does admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims and then do the function request. GC should then hopefully know about the token's new claims.
2. Also about claims; generate a new token (based on current ID token?) and set claims.aud to the URL of the function. The ID token I'm using has claims.aud=projectname which I'm not sure what means.
3. Verify token in function code by using firebase admin. But the authorization of access is still not performed, so this approach seems to miss something.

**What is required?**
I suppose authentication is ok, Google Cloud should recognize the bearer token (?) but I've also read that there's no built-in functionality for this. Anyway, the authorization part is less clear to me when it comes to function requests on user level.

**To summarize**:
How should we authorize an ID token from Identity Platform to Google Cloud Functions? Could any of the three above-mentioned approaches be used?

Comment: Did you tried to follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/identity-platform)? It's with Cloud Run and Firebase, but with Cloud Identity platform (based on Firebase auth) and Cloud Functions (which share the same underlying infrastructure as Cloud Run), it should also work.

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere! Thanks for your response! So the solution will be to give allUsers the invocation role and then do a custom verification of the token with middleware in the function app?